# passing props to react-router-loader

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am currently lazy loading my routes by using react-router-loader. Since I am not referencing the actual component such as:

```
<MyComponent testProp='test' />
```

I would like to find a simple way of passing test prop to the following:

```
<Match exactly pattern='/myComponent' component={require('react-router?name=myComponent!./comps/MyComponent')} />
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `<Match>` component from? React Router v4 does not have a Match component as far as I can see.

Comment: yes it is in "react-router": "4.0.0-alpha.4" - import { BrowserRouter, Match, Miss, Link } from 'react-router'